# How to check if e-mail is full?

Tags: php, validation, email

Is there any way how to check response for e-mail status in PHP script? For example - if I have php script which uses functions like `$mail->Send()` - is there any way how to check return statuses before sending this email? It just check or send "fake" email or something to know for example if e-mail is full or other errors like these:

```
Remote host said: 552 4.2.2 User has full mailbox.
```

Or something like this:

```
Remote host said: 550 5.1.1 Sorry, no mailbox here by that name.
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really doubt you could do that because it would mean that bad intentioned people could scan servers for email addresses.

Comment: Even if I own the SMTP server which sends these emails with username and password which returns these errors? Is it possible in this case somehow?

Comment: perhaps there's a reason for all these restrictions.. a good reason.